# Error with relative paths when running cygwin bash file from cmd

Tags: cmd, cygwin, relative-path

I have cygwin bash.sh file that contains the following:

**bash.sh:**

> cd "data processing"

"data processing" at the same directory of  bash.sh

I'm trying to run this bash file from cmd not cygwin for some reason.
First, I've updated the path environment variable with cygwin bin directory.

**cmd command:**

```
cd "<the-bash-file-directory>" 
bash --login -c "bash '<the-bash-file-directory>\\bash.sh'"
```

then it gives me that error:

**error**

> cd: data processing: No such file or directory

I'm a beginner in using cmd and cygwin and really stuck lots of the time at running things from each other and conflating paths!

Answer (score 0):

Because bash.sh isn't being run from `<the-bash-file-directory>`. It's being run from your home directory. The `--login` switch is causing that to happen. You need to do something like this:

```
bash --login -c "cd <the-bash-file-directory> && ./bash.sh"
```

or get rid of the `--login` switch if you can:

```
cd "<the-bash-file-directory>"
bash -c "./bash.sh"
```